# Query works on SQL Query Analyzer, but fails on PHP mssql_query()

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a complex MSSQL query with multiple joins. When I query using SQL Query Analyzer, it returns results after consuming about 5 minutes. However, when I query using PHP `mssql_query()` function, it returns an error `mssql_query() failed` with no useful information.

Followings are the analysis of this problem so far.

1. Response time limit of php server is not a problem. Time limit is set to infinite. In fact, this same query returns results after about 30 seconds on different production servers.
2. I tried using mssql_get_last_message() to get more details on why it failed. But so far, no luck. All I get is "Changed database context to 'dbsdb'", where 'dbsdb' is the name of database I am querying.

This is the query I am using, if that matters.

```
SELECT L.[strStation], L.[nEntitlement1], L.[nEntitlement2], O.nOrders,
        L.[nEntitlement3], L.[nEntitlement4], S.[strFirm], S.[nStatus],
        S.[nFeatures], S.[nFeatures2], S.[nFeatures3], S.[strDescription]
FROM   [tblLogin] AS L
LEFT JOIN [tblStation] AS S ON L.[strStation] = S.[strStation]
     LEFT JOIN (
                   SELECT [strStation], COUNT(DISTINCT(nRecordId)) as nOrders
                   FROM   [tblOrder]
                   WHERE  [timeOrderDate] >= '2013-06-04' AND
                          [timeOrderDate] <= '2013-06-28'
                   GROUP BY strStation
               ) AS O ON O.[strStation] = S.[strStation]
        WHERE  L.[timeLoginTime] >= '2013-06-04 00:00:00' AND
               L.[timeLoginTime] <= '2013-06-28 23:59:59' AND
               S.[strFirm] in ('FIRMA','FIRMB')
```

This is the code that I use to query.

```
$link = mssql_connect('192.168.251.90', 'sa', '');
if (!mssql_select_db('dbsdb', $link))
    var_dump(mssql_get_last_message());
$query = mssql_query($sql, $link);
```

**EDIT I**

I narrowed down to one spot. When I remove `O.nOrders` part from the SELECT clause, the query works perfectly fine.

But WHY???

**EDIT II**

This is driving me crazy. Query works sometimes even with `O.nOrders` part in SELECT clause. This seems totally random to me, but I know there is no such thing as real random in this world...there should be a reason...

Comment: so did you selected your db? `mssql_select_db('yourdb');`

Comment: you should be using PDO. Then you can use try-catch.

Comment: @Akam Yes. I added the code I use to query the database

Comment: @A.O. I wish I could, but at the moment, I don't have a choice since we are developing on Windows and Linux with MSSQL 2000.

Comment: use: `if(!mssql_select_db('dbsdb', $link)) die(var_dump(mssql_get_last_message()))`

Comment: @Akam I still get query failed error. As I mentioned in the post, it works on different server using same code. It just doesn't work on this specific server...

Comment: Try to wrap the query in a stored procedure and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @mzedeler You mean in the analyzer? The query works fine in analyzer even without stored procedure. I'm sorry but I'm not getting your point...

Comment: So you tried calling a stored procedure that executes this query from php already?